# How to get Identity User Data from Asp.net mvc Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, identity

I have a model as below :

```
public class BaseModel 
{
    public DateTime? CrDate { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CrUser")]
    public ApplicationUser UserCr { get; set; }
    public string CrUser { get; set; }

    public DateTime? MdDate { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("MdUser")]
    public ApplicationUser UserMd { get; set; }
    public string MdUser { get; set; }


    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }



    public void LogWhatever()
    {
        this.CrDate = System.DateTime.Now;
        this.CrUser = ?????
    }

}
```

How can i get the logged userID from model to store in CrUser ?

regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asp.net Identity expose *IUser(IdentityUser)* Context, once user logged in.

```
Context.User.Identity.GetUserId()
```

Comment: Should i only, write Context.User.Identity.GetUserId() ?? It is not working, since not found the context ?

Comment: HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId(); is the right answer ? That is solve my question but is it good approach ?

Comment: are you able to access HttpContext in your model ? and this is exact way/approach how usercontext should be available to the application. let me know i'll have a look then.